# Receiving negative counts in targeted monthly searches

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client

********RESOLVED****************

This was a result of dummy data from using a test MCC account. For any others who encounter a similar issue, note that the dummy data is both massive (ie 6863209244739200390) and may be positive or negative.

********Original question***********

I am trying to use the [TargetingIdeaService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201402/TargetingIdeaService) to get the targeted monthly searches using the Google API. The problem I'm encountering is the count in some of the months is negative. If it helps, I think this is related to what I believe is another problem with the monthly count being massive. I'm just starting in on the Adwords API so I can't say I'm very familiar with it (easy to make minor mistakes). If anyone is aware of the likely root of the problem, please let me know.

```
$selector = new TargetingIdeaSelector();
$selector->requestType = 'STATS';
$selector->ideaType = 'KEYWORD';
$selector->requestedAttributeTypes = ['TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES'];
$selector->localeCode = 'US';

$paging = new Paging();
$paging->startIndex = 0;
$paging->numberResults = 10;
$selector->paging = $paging;

$keywords = new RelatedToQuerySearchParameter();
$keywords->queries = ['garden tools'];

$location = new location();
$location->id = '2840';
$locationTargetParameter = new LocationSearchParameter();
$locationTargetParameter->locations = [$location];

$language = new Language();
$language->id = '1000';
$languageSearchParameter = new LanguageSearchParameter();
$languageSearchParameter->languages = $language;

$selector->searchParameters = [$keywords, $locationTargetParameter, $languageSearchParameter];
$result = $ideaService->get($selector);
```